# C++ Singleton undefined reference to

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, singleton

I am new to C++ and trying to understand the Singleton Pattern in C++.

**myclass.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

class Myclass {
    public:
        static Myclass* getInstance();

    private:
        Myclass(){}
        Myclass(Myclass const&){}
        Myclass& operator=(Myclass const&){}
        static Myclass* m_instance;
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
#include "myclass.h"

Myclass* Myclass::getInstance() {
    if (!m_instance) {
        m_instance = new Myclass;
    }

    return m_instance;
}
```

The compiler can't compile. I get the following error, on all 3 lines with `m_instance`:

error: undefined reference to `Myclass::m_instance'

Comment: Actually, there is a better way to implement Singleton. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/9783282).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You forgot to add:

```
Myclass* Myclass::m_instance = 0; // or NULL, or nullptr in c++11
```

right under `#include "myclass.h"`.